# if statment comparing day of the week in android java allways returning true

Tags: java, android, calendar

I know it seems a logic error, i have reviewed this a couple times, everything seems right, if someone can point me the right direction:

We have a service that is called at specific times, 10 am, 4 pm and 11pm.
The service works fine, the notification is created.
BUT, when we put the logic to compare the day of the week, it is called everyday even if its not the day in question.

code snipet:

```
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    if (day == Calendar.SATURDAY || day == Calendar.WEDNESDAY); //always true
    {
        if(hour == 10 || hour == 16) //correct regardless of anterior
        {
            //create notification


        }
        else if(hora == 23)
        {
            //create other type of intent

        }
    }
    super.onStart(intent, startId);     

}
```

Comment: So how i solve this issue? i need it to be called only on saturdays and wednesdays...

Comment: `if (day == Calendar.SATURDAY || day == Calendar.WEDNESDAY);` Can't be always true

Answer (score 6):

You are not getting the expected result because you put semi column after if statement

```
 if (day == Calendar.SATURDAY || day == Calendar.WEDNESDAY);
```

Remove the Semi column.

Comment: GZUS CHRIST, i almost lost my job because of a semicollon? u saved my life!

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is not always true; the semicolon separates the if statement from the following code block, making them independent.

So the if statement is evaluated, and then the code block is executed without relying on the if outcome to determine if it should be executed.

Comment: May look like im a complete idiot, or beginner, but neither of those, i just lack attention to details... ill try to read semicollons b4 posting again, thanks anyway.